# Excel VBA to Export Selected Sheets to PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export

I'm using the following code to export selected sheets from Excel 2010 to a single pdf file...

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="C:\temp.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

My problem is that it only exports the first sheet.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 30):

Once you have Selected a group of sheets, you can use **Selection**

Consider:

```
Sub luxation()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="C:\TestFolder\temp.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Further testing has reveled that this technique depends on the group of cells **selected** on each worksheet.  To get a comprehensive output, use something like:

```
Sub Macro1()

   Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
   Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
   Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
   Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
      "C:\Users\James\Desktop\pdfmaker.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
      True
End Sub
```

Comment: this only prints a blank sheet for me. not sure why?

Comment: Using Selection only seems to export a blank sheet in Excel 2013.  The use of ActiveSheet as seen in ASP8811 and HattrickNZ's answers did work for us.

Comment: you get a +1 for a good answer but also for the name of your sub. that's very clever.

Comment: `Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat` only exports the selected cell or leads to empty PDF-Prints also in Office 365 (Office 2016).
One has to export sheet by sheet as time being.

Answer (score 9):

I'm pretty mixed up on this. I am also running Excel 2010. I tried saving two sheets as a single PDF using:

```
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(1,2)).Select
    **Selection**.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, FileName & ".pdf", , , False
```

but I got nothing but blank pages. It saved both sheets, but nothing on them. It wasn't until I used:

```
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(1,2)).Select
    **ActiveSheet**.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, FileName & ".pdf", , , False
```

that I got a single PDF file with both sheets.

I tried manually saving these two pages using Selection in the Options dialog to save the two sheets I had selected, but got blank pages. When I tried the Active Sheet(s) option, I got what I wanted. When I recorded this as a macro, Excel used ActiveSheet when it successfully published the PDF. What gives?

Comment: what is FileName equal to? can `FileName` in clude a path? [myref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238907%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: I am now getting an error with this `Array(1,2)` what is this meant to be? its like it will only accept 1 worksheet name?

Comment: Sorry this is after the fact. I haven't logged on in awhile. Filename should include the file path to the location you want to save to as well as the file name.

Answer (score 4):

this is what i came up with as i was having issues with @asp8811 answer(maybe my own difficulties)

' this will do the put the first 2 sheets in a pdf
    ' Note each ws should be controlled with page breaks for printing which is a bit fiddly
    ' this will explicitly put the pdf in the current dir

```
Sub luxation2()
    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = "temp201"



Dim shtAry()
ReDim shtAry(1) ' this is an array of length 2
For i = 1 To 2
shtAry(i - 1) = Sheets(i).Name
Debug.Print Sheets(i).Name
Next i
Sheets(shtAry).Select
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"


    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Filename & ".pdf", , , False

End Sub
```

Comment: Mine only works with the first two sheets because that's what I was going for in my code. My answer wasn't really an answer, more of a clarification about using ActiveSheet instead of Selection because I didn't have the reputation to comment at the time. Your solution is much better for using multiple sheets.