# Export Different Sheets in one excel file to different pdf files?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel, pdf

I have an excel file which has 10 sheets. We can use below to export the entire excel file to one pdf file.

```
ExportAsFixedFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, outputPath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Is it possible to export each sheet as a pdf file? So totally, I have 10 pdf files?

WorkSheet.SaveAs can save the sheet, but it does not export to pdf.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750854/excel-vba-to-export-selected-sheets-to-pdf

Comment: I agree. The VBA answer is not for C#. The answer from MeHow works fine for C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may need to iterate the Sheets(*spreadsheets & chart sheets*)/Worksheets(*spreadsheets only*) and export each sheet individually.

```
// add using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
// wb - workbook reference
foreach (Worksheet workSht in wb.Sheets)
{
    if (workSht.UsedRange.Cells.Count > 0)
    {
        workSht.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, 
                                                      outputPath + workSht.Name);
     }
 }
```

Comment: thanks. it works. I did not know it is WorkSheet instead of Sheet. That's why I could not find ExportAsFixedFormat for the sheet.