# Export excel text as an image file

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I finally was able to export excel text as .jpg image file using Excel VBA. I was able to find articles/posts/blogs on how to export a picture/clipart as an image but could not find anything on text. Now that finally I was able to do it, the picture that gets exported is blurry. **Please advice how can I get a good picture quality**. Here is the exported picture. It looks good on excel but not as a picture. I tried changing the format as .png with not much of a difference. Fonts used Monotype Corsiva for heading and Times New Roman Italics for text.
[image]
My text is in the range A1:L21 and here is the code that I found somewhere on the Internet which was modified as per my needs

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportMyTextAsPicture()

     Dim MyChart As String, MyPicture As String
     Dim PicWidth As Long, PicHeight As Long

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     On Error GoTo Finish

    Range("A1:L21").Select
    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    Range("A23").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

     MyPicture = Selection.Name
     With Selection
           PicHeight = .ShapeRange.Height
           PicWidth = .ShapeRange.Width
     End With

     Charts.Add
     ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1"
     Selection.Border.LineStyle = 0
     MyChart = Selection.Name & " " & Split(ActiveChart.Name, " ")(2)

     With ActiveSheet
           With .Shapes(MyChart)
                 .Width = PicWidth
                 .Height = PicHeight
           End With

           .Shapes(MyPicture).Copy

           With ActiveChart
                 .ChartArea.Select
                 .Paste
           End With

           .ChartObjects(1).Chart.Export Filename:="mymymy.jpg", FilterName:="jpg"
           .Shapes(MyChart).Cut
     End With

     ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Select
     Selection.Cut

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Exit Sub

Finish:
     MsgBox "You must select a picture"
End Sub
```

**Here is the original code (incase anyone needs it)** that I searched for... to export picture/clipart. (The image needs to be selected before running the macro)

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportMyPicture()

     Dim MyChart As String, MyPicture As String
     Dim PicWidth As Long, PicHeight As Long

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     On Error GoTo Finish


     MyPicture = Selection.Name
     With Selection
           PicHeight = .ShapeRange.Height
           PicWidth = .ShapeRange.Width
     End With

     Charts.Add
     ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1"
     Selection.Border.LineStyle = 0
     MyChart = Selection.Name & " " & Split(ActiveChart.Name, " ")(2)

     With ActiveSheet
           With .Shapes(MyChart)
                 .Width = PicWidth
                 .Height = PicHeight
           End With

           .Shapes(MyPicture).Copy

           With ActiveChart
                 .ChartArea.Select
                 .Paste
           End With

           .ChartObjects(1).Chart.Export Filename:="mymymy.jpg", FilterName:="jpg"
           .Shapes(MyChart).Cut
     End With

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Exit Sub

Finish:
     MsgBox "You must select a picture"
End Sub
```

Comment: Unrelated, but "future" has a typo that you might want to fix ;)

Comment: Thanks for your advice... I will try the pdf approach

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation. I created the information in Excel that needed to be created into images. The image would always be saved as a compressed image, especially with the fonts. It would not save the fonts as anti-aliased. To go around that, I printed/saved it as a PDF file instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also save to PDF programmatically using VBA, as discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750854/excel-vba-to-export-selected-sheets-to-pdf) and on [this site](http://www.contextures.com/excelvbapdf.html).