# Export Excel to PDF with formula values using vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, pdf

I am trying to export an excel file (xlsx type)to PDF. not all the values are showing when i have formula.

```
Dim xl As Object
            xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            Dim xwb As Object = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\sahara\Code\OperationSummaryReport\Book1.xlsx")
            xwb.ActiveSheet.calculate()
            xwb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, "C:\sahara\Code\OperationSummaryReport\sample.pdf", _
            XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, _
            True, _
            True, _
            1, _
            10, _
            True)


            xl.Quit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA to Export Selected Sheets to PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750854/excel-vba-to-export-selected-sheets-to-pdf)

Comment: No it's a different case. when i am trying to open Excel and save it manually as PDF it works. but when i tried to export from the code as pdf, i got #NAME?  as value

Comment: even i tried another way by opening the Excel file and calculate and copy and paste using paste special and getting the same result.Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
            Dim wsDst As Worksheet

            wsSrc = excelWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            wsDst = excelWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
            wsSrc.Activate()
            wsSrc.Calculate()
            wsSrc.Range("B2:B3").Copy()

            wsDst.Range("B2").PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, Transpose:=False)
            excelWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Application.CutCopyMode = False