# Macro for creating a PDF of multiple different ranges across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to make a macro that creates a PDF file of different specified ranges across different sheets. The current code im working with:

```
 Sub Macro1()

Sheets("Administratief").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F22").Select
Sheets("Spuiwater TID").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B4:F17").Select

Sheets(Array("Administratief", "Spuiwater TID")).Select

Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    FormName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    True
    
End Sub
```

The problem with this is that it uses the range of "A1:F22" in both sheets instead of using the range of B4:B17. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with VBA yet (getting to know the basics myself, just recently). But perhaps you could try to copy both ranges into a new sheet, then work out what you are doing with the data (putting them in an array and outputting into a PDF), and then delete the newly created sheet.

My way of 'learning' VBA is by basically recording a macro of whatever I'm doing, then putting them together in a way that I feel like it should work.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You could even just keep the new Sheet, but then make sure you don't create a new one every time.

Comment: seems a duplicate with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47099711/saving-multiple-ranges-on-two-different-sheets-to-pdf-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

Try it, maybe this is what you wanted? Saves the selected ranges into two separate PDF files, maybe I misunderstood you. Part of the code was found on this forum and adapted to your needs.
**The user chooses the range himself:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Export_v1()
    Dim shArr       As Variant
    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim strPath     As String
    Dim myFile      As Variant
    Dim rng         As Range
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set shArr = Sheets(Array("Administratief", "Spuiwater TID"))
    strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    If strPath = "" Then
        strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    End If

    strPath = strPath & "\"

    For Each shArr In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        ' The user chooses the range himself
        Set rng = Application.InputBox("Please, Select a Range: ", "Prompt to select a range for the print area on the selected worksheet", Type:=8).Areas(1)
        shArr.PageSetup.PrintArea = rng.Address

        myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
                (InitialFileName:=strPath, _
                FileFilter:="PDF (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
                Title:="Select folder and filename to save")

        shArr.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=myFile, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=False
        Set rng = Nothing
    Next shArr

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not export file", vbCritical, "Export"
    Resume exitHandler
    Set shArr = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Fixed range without request:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Export_v2()
    Dim shArr       As Variant
    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim strPath     As String
    Dim myFile      As Variant
    Dim rng         As Range
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set shArr = Sheets(Array("Administratief", "Spuiwater TID"))
    strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    If strPath = "" Then
        strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    End If

    strPath = strPath & "\"

    For Each shArr In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        ' Fixed range without request
        If shArr.Name = "Administratief" Then
            shArr.PageSetup.PrintArea = shArr.Range("A1:F22").Address
        
        ElseIf shArr.Name = "Spuiwater TID" Then
            shArr.PageSetup.PrintArea = shArr.Range("B4:F17").Address
        Else

        End If

        myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
                (InitialFileName:=strPath, _
                FileFilter:="PDF (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
                Title:="Select folder and filename to save")

        shArr.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=myFile, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=False
        Set rng = Nothing
    Next shArr

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not export file", vbCritical, "Export"
    Resume exitHandler
    Set shArr = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Good luck.

Comment: What you can do in cases where one depends on user input and the other one doesn't, is only having the userinput in the one sub and then sending info/variables through to the main sub. For the fixed range, just send those as variables to the main sub.

Comment: @Notus_Panda, I provided completely two different options, the two procedures are independent of each other.  In one procedure, the user himself sets (indicates) the range, and in the second procedure there are strictly fixed ranges, for each specified sheet there is its own range.  It is up to the user to decide which procedure to use for himself.

Comment: I am aware you provided two independent ones. However, to save code/rewriting things, you can make a sub take arguments and therefor re-use one sub for both scenarios.

Comment: Dear @Notus_Panda, can you provide a working code example?  I will study your example since I am self-taught, I do not have this education in VBA programming.  I learn from such forums.  Thank you.

Comment: It's similar like you'd pass arguments to a function, [example passing argument to sub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33899319/19353309). In your case, you'd have 2 different subs calling the main sub by passing either the `"A1:F22"` and `"B4:F17"` as the static addresses or you'd take the input from the user and pass the address as a string the same way as the other sub would. Then you use those arguments in `shArr.Range("strRng1").Address`  while having `Sub ExportMain(strRng1 As String, strRng2 As String)` for example.